# IIS: logging client certificate's thumbprint

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, authentication, iis-7.5, https

On IIS 7.5, with client authentication by certificate, how to enable logging of client certificate's thumbprint (or serial, or subject dn) to IIS log?

Comment: I don't know why this was marked down; its an entirely sensible question for SSL client certificate authentication.

Answer (score 2):

While I am not proficient in IIS in particular (I deal with Apache mostly), I would expect this is be a custom logging sort of thing.

The following page documents some of the advanced logging functionality of IIS; while it doesn't show SSL things in the screenshots, it may still be useful.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/advanced-logging-module/advanced-logging-for-iis-custom-logging

Note also the doucmentation around IIS server variables, which I would expect to be able to be logged in a custom logging situation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms524602.aspx

That page does list various Client Authentication server variables.

Cheers,
Cameron

Answer (score 1):

You can use server variables to log a CERT_COOKIE (unique identifier) and the incoming subject and the issuer subject of the certificate.

However, the CERT_Cookie is generated by IIS and does not contain the thumbprint.

Possible values in the advanced logging (logging tools) settings:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-dev-reference/server-variables

(So it still remains a mystery to us why our CA certificate is rejected.)